# how to stop SparkContext which is created inside function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function to create SparkContext and SQLContext.

```
 def init_spark(query=None):
     def quiet_logs( sc ):
       logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
       logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
       logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )

     if 'sc' in locals():
         sc.stop()
     conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
     conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
     conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
     conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
     conf.set("es.read.field.exclude", "data.integrations")

     if query:
         conf.set("es.query", query)

     sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
     quiet_logs(sc)

     sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
     return sqlContext
```

apparently sc.stop() check doesn't work, and I tried doing that outside of function, still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at the [getOrCreate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate) and [newSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.newSession), you can stop the current one first, then create a new one from config, so you don't have to do Python level of checking.

```
# Stop whatever you are getting here
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().stop()

# New session with your config
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).newSession()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Now the first part seems inefficient (if there were no session, it will create one then kill it), not sure how much overhead it causes.

**edit:** Or pull `sc` to outside, and check if it's assigned

```
sc = None

def init_spark(query=None):

  global sc

  if sc is not None:
    sc.stop()

  ...

  sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

  ...
```